# mysql time sum from two different tables

Tags: mysql, nested, sum

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b814c/6/0

```
select listener, SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(time))) as total_time, count(listener) as total_listened from db1 where date = "2013-02-20" group by listener
```

How can i add db2 values to this query?

I tried nested queries, but it runs too slow and doesn't show only db2 listeners.

Both tables in different databases if it changes something.

Result should be like for this sample;

```
LISTENER    TOTAL_TIME  TOTAL_LISTENED
listener1   00:15:39    1
listener2   00:22:59    2
listener3   00:13:34    1
```

Comment: Why not just use `UNION ALL`?

Comment: Not only that, but use a better primary key, like an auto incremented id. Any reason that you're separating date and time?

Comment: @njk There is, but i didnt put it in sample. Time is the duration of listened part, not clock.

Comment: @ExplosionPills It gives multiple values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your original query

```
select listener, SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(time))) as total_time,
count(listener) as total_listened from db1 where date = "2013-02-20"
group by listener
```

Try combining the `listener` and `time` columns

Then, apply your operations aginst their UNION

```
SET @GivenDate='2013-02-20';
SELECT listener,SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(time))) as total_time,
COUNT(listener) as total_listened
FROM
(
    SELECT listener,time FROM db1
    where date = @GivenDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT listener,time FROM db2
    where date = @GivenDate
) A GROUP BY listener;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for?

```
select listener, SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(time))) as total_time, count(listener) as total_listened from 
(
  SELECT * FROM db1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM db2
) A
where date = "2013-02-20" group by listener
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b814c/10)**

Comment: I accepted other answer because it was earlier, but i will use this. What does that "A" (in both answers) do?

Comment: @milesh It is just alias, every table (subquery) must have alias.